# Azure Resource Graph Explorer :: list all resourceGroup with subscriptionName

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-resource-group, kusto-explorer, azure-resource-graph

I've created a kusto query that will allow me to have an overview of all resourceGroups:

```
resourcecontainers
where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups'
project subscriptionId, resourceGroup,  tags.mytag1, tags.mytag2, tags.mytag3
```

Is there a way I can project the `subscriptionName` instead of the `subscriptionId`?

the goal is to make it more human readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, that is possible by joining on the resourcecontainers of type `microsoft.resources/subscriptions`:

```
resourcecontainers
| where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions' 
| project subscriptionId, subscriptionName = name 
| join (resourcecontainers 
    | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups') 
    on subscriptionId 
| project subscriptionName, resourceGroup, tags.mytag1, tags.mytag2, tags.mytag3
```

Comment: Ah, you teach me something today @Peter. Thanks a million.

Comment: Hi @Peter, I checked the code today but your query just returns me 14 results which is the number of subscriptions and it returns me 1 resourceGroups per subscription. But with my previous query I was able to retrieve >500 resourceGroups which is the actual number of resourceGroups we have

Comment: I updated your code. Now it works